# My website looks fine in internet explorer but it looks bad in chrome.. why?

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I built a website josephhyatt.com and when im trying to edit it with css and use chrome nothing responds to my css changes, it will just stay the same, but in internet explorer it responds to all changes i make and looks how i want it.  Any reason why chrome is doing that? thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe you use any deprecated **CSS**rules or **cross-browser** compatibility issue , Like you need  vendor prefix (`-webkit` for Chrome, Safari; `-moz `for Firefox, `-o` for Opera, `-ms` for Internet Explorer). Try use vendor prefix

Answer (score 2):

There could be 2 reasons for this.

Number ZERO. If you cache your website, you may need to update your .manifest file or clear your browser's cache. This way your site will be downloaded again instead of loading a local copy.

Number ONE. Probably you don't pay attention to cross-browser CSS techniques. Maybe you should learn more about CSS compatibility for different browsers ( [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is a good choice ).